# How to avoid multiple identical IDs with Telerik grids?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, duplicates

I have the following situation:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)

@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductModel.ProductDataSampleModel>()
    .Name("productdatasample-grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x.Id))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("ProductDataSampleList", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id })
        .Insert("ProductDataSampleInsert", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id })
        .Update("ProductDataSampleUpdate", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id })
        .Delete("ProductDataSampleDelete", "Product")
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
        columns.Bound(x => x.Description);
        columns.Command(commands => { commands.Edit(); commands.Delete(); });
    })
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .EnableCustomBinding(true))
)
```

As you can see, there are two edit fields `Name` and `Description` on the form, and also two edit fields with the same name in the grid. The fields on the form each create an input element like:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
<input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" />
```

When I insert or edit a row in the grid, another two textboxes **with the same names and ids** get created. The names wouldn't be a problem, but having two elements with the same ID on a page creates all sorts of confusion.

What is the proper way to solve this dilemma?

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to use TexboxFor instead of the EditorFor for your custom fields: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = 'MyEditorName'}) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { id = 'MyEditorDescription'})`

Comment: @nemesv - That's one way, but it required to carefully follow all new fields that get added to the form (even in grids), which can get pretty tedious pretty quickly if the form is as complicated as the one in question (10 tabs, several grids, many fields...). And if you're already doing that then might as well just change the model field name - the same amount of effort, just cleaner. I was wondering about something that solved this automagically (auto-generated namespace-prefixes?)